# Curly Braces around text groups with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, braces

I would like to achieve the following
[image]

What I have by now is
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{makecell}%

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[] (n1) {\makecell[l]{
                weiß nicht\\
                kann nicht\\
                will nicht\\
                werde nicht\\
                Pups
        }};
        \node[right=of n1] (g1) {Gruppe 1};
        
        \node[below=of n1] (n2) {\makecell[l]{
                lang und nochmal lang\\
                viele Sachen, die auch mal viel Text bedeuten\\
                Spass
        }};
        \node[right=of n2] (g2) {Gruppe 2};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left] (n1) {
weiß nicht\\
kann nicht\\
will nicht\\
werde nicht\\
Pups
};
\node[right=of n1] (g1) {Gruppe 1};
\node[below=of n1, align=left] (n2) {
lang und nochmal lang\\
viele Sachen, die auch mal viel Text bedeuten\\
Spass
};
\node[right=of n2] (g2) {Gruppe 2};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (n1.north east) -- (n1.south east);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (n2.north east) -- (n2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Text with braces]

Edit: I have just now seen that you also want different alignment:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[align=left] (n1) {
weiß nicht\\
kann nicht\\
will nicht\\
werde nicht\\
Pups
};
\node[right=of n1] (g1) {Gruppe 1};
\node[below=of n1.south west, anchor=north west, align=left] (n2) {
lang und nochmal lang\\
viele Sachen, die auch mal viel Text bedeuten\\
Spass
};
\node[right=of n2] (g2) {Gruppe 2};
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (n1.north east) -- (n1.south east);
\draw[decorate, decoration={brace, amplitude=10pt}] (n2.north east) -- (n2.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Left aligned text with braces]